# Storing variable in Jersey web application

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

The question is about a web application using Jersey / JAX-RS.

In the code below, I want each user to have his own individual instance of the variable x, so that he can set it to a new value and then retrieve that new value. As it is now the value is not stored.

(It seems necessary to store the variable in the Java and not in a HTTP-session, as I want to do the same thing for another class instance, that can not be stored in a HTTP-session.)

Code example:

@Path("/")
public class Web implements Web_Interface {

```
private int x = 9;

public Response getValue() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String gsonString = gson.toJson("X = " + x);
    return Response
            .ok(gsonString)
            .build();
}

public Response setValue(int newX) {
    x = newX;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String gsonString = gson.toJson("X was set to " + newX);
    return Response
            .ok(gsonString)
            .build();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you are using HTTP than you need to first clear about HTTP is StateLess,

when you call setValue() than it sets a value

but when you call getValue() than new session is created so old value is flushed.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey doesn't have sessions. The rest protocol is stateless. It's not really clear what your question is, but if you want to associate a variable with a user and allow them to change it you really have 3 options

1) Ignore that the rest protocol is stateless and wire up the httpsession in jersey (it's not there by default but it can be done, you will have to make it work by attaching a session to the context and getting it back yourself).

2) Put it in a cookie

3) Put it in a database of some sort and retrieve it for the user (you will have to use a cookie or some sort of authentication to identify your user)

Comment: Like I said, you can wire up the httpsession but it's not there automatically.